# If I own a business facebook page, but am separated from the company, do I legally have to turn over the page?

Tags: employer-relations, quitting

I started a business facebook page on my own profile several years ago.  I built it into over 3,000 fans (likes).  I've been with the company over 15 years and am now separating from the company due to some issues that have made me lose faith. 
We are in mediation, but, more than likely, they are going to try to get me to quit without my severance and I will have to take the issue to court (whistle-blower, discrimination & constructive discharge).
The question is - am I legally required to turn over the facebook page to the company?  Am I legally allowed to delete it?

Thanks so any help!

Comment: I would suggest consulting a lawyer

Comment: What purpose would deleting the page serve, other than revenge? It appears you're not acting in good faith.

Comment: "I started a business facebook page on my own profile several years ago"  As in the account is with your real name but your entire profile is about the business?  Or did you start a fan page or something?  If its your name but you used it to promote the business, that was pretty foolish.

Comment: This is off-topic for us but if you add information about your jurisdiction, we could try sending it over to the Law site.  They won't be able to help you if you don't indicate whose laws you're subject to, though.  If you [edit] this into your question, please flag to request migration.

Comment: @Andy just guessing, but from my experience with Facebook, I suspect that it's a page for the business, in the name of the business, but his personal Facebook account is the owning administrator. I haven't dealt with this for a couple of years but I recall it was impossible to transfer that ownership back when I last needed to do so.

Comment: @Carson63000 they can move the page administrator to point to a different account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I'm not a lawyer.*

I think you don't have many rights in this case. It all depends on the type and content of the page.
**Is there anything specified in your contract?** Then that will be leading.
**Is it a fan page?** If that's the case you might be able to keep it.
**Is it the official page of the company?** Then you will probally have to hand it over to them.
**Did you make/maintain it in company time?** Chances it's legally theirs.

It also carries their name, which they'll probally have rights to, which will you will lose. I suggest you contact a lawyer, you might want to get one to consult with to explore the possibilities.

---

In the context of the question you might use it differently. It seems like they want to screw you over ("take it to court"). You both don't really want this, since it costs money and time. This Facebookpage might give you some leverage, maybe you can trade it in for something (make sure you get the agreement on paper!), make it a win-win for both.
Revenge will result in burning bridges and you'll never know when it'll come back to bite you in the behind.

Comment: I don't think trying to use the facebook page as leverage would be very professional; otherwise I think your answer is good.

Comment: Leverage might be a too harsh word, but he has something they want, they have something he might benefit from.

Comment: @Martijn: He has something the he *likely* has zero *legal* rights over.  Keeping it from them would not be in his interest in any scenario.

Comment: I generally wouldn't be concerned about "burning bridges" with an employer who is actively trying to screw me over.

Comment: @JamesAdam True, but a court might find deletion of the facebook page as showing the employee is acting in bad faith, and they might be able to sue him for damages.

Answer (score 2):

If you have any clauses in your employment contract regarding intellectual property, or terms governing rights to claim interest in work produced, then the Facebook page may very well be considered the property of the company. With 3,000 likes (and assuming they are organic likes from customers, word of mouth marketing or pay per click marketing), the company will more than likely want to retain the page. Since you are leaving, the best and simplest thing you can do is simply turn over the page to the company. Let them decide whether they want to keep it or not. The last thing you want is to delete it or keep it and have it some how construed as theft or used against you and your reputation down the road. Make a clean cut for the best and retain integrity in the process.

Comment: I don't this is what the TS wants to know, I'm asumming they *don't* want to give it away